# vuetify navigation drawer cannot be clicked

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I created a navigation drawer using Vuetify but none of the menus can be clicked.
Here's the code

```
<v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" temporary app class="primary">
    <v-list>
        <v-list-item v-for="link in links" :key="link.text" link :to="link.path">
            <v-list-item-action>
                <v-icon class="white--text">{{link.icon}}</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-action>
            <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title class="white--text">{{link.text}}</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
    </v-list>
    <template v-slot:append>
            <div class="pa-2">
                <v-btn block>
                    Sign out
                    <v-icon right>mdi-exit-to-app</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
            </div>
        </template>
</v-navigation-drawer>

data() {
  return {
    drawer: false,
    links: [
      {icon: 'mdi-view-dashboard', text: 'Dashboard', path: '/'},
      {icon: 'mdi-application-edit', text: 'Settings', path: '/settings'}
    ]
  }
}
```

I have checked the routes in `index.js` and there is nothing wrong there. Also, if I go to `/settings` page, the Setting menu will be highlighted (active) but still cannot be clicked. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! The Navbar component was nested in a `v-app-bar` and somehow it affected the navbar. So I only removed the `v-app-bar` and the navigation drawer works perfectly fine!